# Seaborn: how to change a logarithmic axis format from scientific to plain and display ticks in all subplots (Facetgrid)

Tags: seaborn, lmplot

I'm using the following code to produce a lmplot. The output is 6 different plots (controlled by the hue parameter).

```
g=sns.lmplot(data=fenix,
           x='x', 
           y='y', 
           hue='var', 
           col="var", 
           fit_reg=False,
           col_wrap=3
          )

g.set(xscale='linear', yscale='log')    

plt.tick_params(axis='y', which='both', direction='out', length=4, left=True)
    
sns.despine()

plt.show()
```

The result only shows the yticks (major and minor) in the last plot (6th plot). Also, I have not find a way to change the y axis format from scientific to plain notation.

Can anyone recommend a way to solve this?
thanks

Comment: Although not the exact same question, the duplicate demonstrates how to use `tick_params` in a for loop

Comment: Hi @Diziet Asahi. I will try it and let you know. What is the flatten() method do?

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html

Comment: Hi @DizietAsahi, I followed the solution on the question that you suggested and it works now. thank you